# Unable to get process status error in Nagios

Tags: nagios

I installed Nagios on my system (Fedora 21) but when I start it from the browser it throws the error:

> Unable to get process status error.

I have added the following lines in my httpd.conf file

```
ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/nagios/sbin/"
```

AllowOverride AuthConfig
         Options ExecCGI
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all

```
 Alias /nagios/ "/usr/local/nagios/share/"
 <Directory "/usr/local/nagios/share/">
     Options None
     AllowOverride AuthConfig
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

nagios.log entries:

> [1423829856] Warning: Return code of 127 for check of service 'Total Processes' on host 'localhost' was out of bounds. Make sure the plugin you're trying to run actually exists.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the resolution was sinply to start the Nagios service as

```
sudo systemctl start nagios.service
```

after which the error that you were seeing as

> Unable to get process status error.

should now look something like

> Daemon running with PID 9027

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issues with the nagios-plugins, You will have to reinstall it. Please try with the following command.

```
yum reinstall nagios-plugins
```

Comment: I reinstalled it still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while upgrading to the newer version of Nagios Core.

After adding the following two lines into nagios.conf:

```
state_retention_file=/usr/local/nagios/var/retention.dat
status_file=/usr/local/nagios/var/status.dat
```

the problem doesn't persist anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pety's answer above, I found that my issue was that the ownership of the directory where the "status_file" and "state_retention_file" did not allow nagios account to read/write files.    Correcting ownership seemed to fix my issue.